# The grammar in «Cómo será de feo, que es más feo que lo de las mujeres»

Tags: gramática, categorías-gramaticales

This sentence "Cómo será de feo, que es más feo que lo de las mujeres" is from the novel "El amor en los tiempos del cólera" by Gabriel GarcíA Márquez. I understand that it means "How ugly it is, even uglier than a woman's thing". My question is on the grammar.

"De" as a preposition should be followed by a noun or something like a noun, for example, "Soy de Barcelona", so I do not understand the "de feo" part. Also the sentence is, when translated to English, "How it will be of ugly", which does not make sense.

If you need context, you can find it here: https://books.google.com/books?id=nui9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Well, _feo_ can be a noun, see the entry in the DLE and the fourth definition. Does that help?

Comment: It helps, but the construction still does not make sense, "it will be of ugliness"? What purpose does the preposition "de" serves?

Comment: I don't know where you found that other translation but it is wrong. You might say in Spanish: No sabemos cómo será de bonita, la boda. We don't know how pretty the wedding will be. ser de + adjective is indeed: how [adjective] something is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Ser + de + adjective" and "estar + de + adjective" are common constructions in Spanish, and will always appear with interrogative or exclamatory adverb "cómo".

I agree with mdewey that the adjective has some nominal force. Actually, I interpret "de + adjective" as "as far as (noun) is concerned", but I think the word after "de" is an adjective:

- ¿Cómo es de alto? (How tall is he?) (Literal, terrible translation: What is he like as far as tallness is concerned?)
- ¿Cómo es de caro? (How expensive is it?) (Literal, terrible translation: What is it like as far as price is concerned?)
- ¡Cómo está de gordo! (How fat he is!) (Literal, terrible translation: How he is as far as fatness is concerned!)

Even though adjectives like "alto" can work as nouns, others like "caro" and "gordo" can't. Therefore, though the structure may be noun-related from a semantic perspective, what follows the preposition is an adjective.

I find this exclamatory or interrogative construction formed by "de" + adjective, where "de" introduces a magnitude, to be closely related to phrases like:

- No tiene un pelo **de tonto**.
- No tiene nada **de divertido**.

Comment: Your explication makes sense and I have marked it as the answer. As a non-native speaker, where should I find the answer apart from posting to this forum? I looked up the "de" entry in the dictionary, such usage is not documented there.

Comment: The point is that the dictionary not always refers to the meaning of prepositions used in idioms like this one.

Comment: @puravidaso Of course it is not "in a dictionary" under de. These are idiomatic uses: ser de [adjective]

Answer (score 1):

que tal!

---

Creo que la frase "Cómo será de feo, que es más feo que lo de las mujeres", no esta aclarada en las respuestas, o al menos eso es lo que interpreto, pues aunque se da una explicación gramatical no ayuda a entender el significado cuando se dice;

***"Cómo será de feo", lo cual no tiene sentido.***

Desde mi punto de vista, en este caso, que puede servir de ejemplo en general, para entender el sentido amplio de la frase, no puedes extraer aquella parte que solo se refiere a "Cómo será de feo", por si sola, a no ser que estés habituado a escucharla y a utilizar.

Cuando alguien dice;

- Como será de gordo.
- Como será de estúpido
- Como será de guapo
- etc...

Para entender estas expresiones iremos a la primera frase.

"Cómo será de feo, que es más feo que lo de las mujeres".

Hay que saber que este tipo de frase es de tipo comparativa, entendiendo por comparación la acción de cotejar dos o más cosas para dar con sus posibles semejanzas, diferencias o relaciones, ya sea apelando a un aspecto físico, simbólico, imaginario... De esa manera, se pueden comparar dos cosas y resaltar sus parecidos ó por el contrario sus diferencias.

---

En Español tenemos tres tipos de comparativa;

- Igualdad
- Inferioridad
- Superioridad

Si observamos la frase;

"Cómo será de feo, que es más feo que lo de las mujeres"

Estamos ante una comparación de superioridad y por tanto uno de los términos es comparado con el otro para acentuar una superioridad, grandeza ó que algo es más que otra cosa. En este tipo de frases se emplean a menudo las fórmulas “mayor que…” o “más que…”.

Así, cuando dices "Cómo será de feo", lo que se esta haciendo es comparando, en este caso con lo más feo que de las mujeres.

---

Este tipo de expresiones en Español no hace falta que especifiquen tanto, y por tanto cuando se emplea;

- Como será de gordo.
- Como será de estúpido
- Como será de guapo
- Como será de bruto
- etc...

lo que estamos haciendo es comparando con otra cosa, que aún no hemos dicho.

- Por otro lado este tipo de fórmula se aplica de forma recurrente cuando se refieren o hacen chistes o bromas.

Ejem. Como será de bruto que... cuando la profesora borraba el ejercicio de la pizarra, ¡él lo borraba de la libreta!

Así, cuando se dice solamente, por ejemplo "Como será de gordo", aunque falte la segunda parte de la comparación, sobrentendemos que es una comparación con algo del mismo grado ó superior.

Espero que te haya ayudado, a pesar del tiempo trascurrido. Saludos.

Diego M.